# Attach file in SharePoint List without using permission Edit

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list, attachments

I've got a list where a particular user group should be able to add items only to this list, but not edit them.

However, these users cannot ATTACH a document to the item they are adding because « edit permission » is disabled.

If I add the "edit items" permission to this group, they are able to attach a document, but then they are able to edit information they shouldn't have access to edit. I search solution who users can add items and attach files without using « edit permission ».

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new editform.aspx in which you disable each field that can't be modified using css and js scripts.

If some other users can modify the items, then you can make a script depending on the sharePoint group.

This blog post may help you : http://spjsblog.com/2012/05/07/showing-or-hiding-form-fields-based-on-membership-in-a-sharepoint-group/

Comment: Although, if the user is familiar with front-end web development, he can easily enable the properties within the form :)